# Cannot instal Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

Thanks Ubuntu for its great OS, two months ago I bought a new Computer to begin learning and using Ubuntu and I had very little problems until yesterday.

Two mounts ago I did successfully install the following ISO images from a DVD

> ubuntu-10.04.4-dvd-amd64.iso & ubuntu-11.10-dvd-amd64.iso

Yesterday I could not install from neither DVD nor USB drives:

> ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso & ubuntu-12.04-dvd-amd64.iso

I succeed to get the first 'ascii' screen only when I immediately press the Escape key (otherwise I get nothing at all), I select then the correct install menu but I get nothing but a dark screen. However it seems that the install menu changes into graphical screen.

In the same computer I can actually install ubuntu-10.04.4-dvd-amd64.iso & ubuntu-11.10-dvd-amd64.iso).

In another oldest computer I can also install ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso

**THE NEW COMPUTER IS:**

```
Machine:   Mobo: ASUSTeK model: P8Z68-V LX version: Rev X.0x Bios: American Megatrends version: 3506 date: 01/17/2012
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i5-2500K CPU
Graphics:  Card: nVidia Device 1244 bus-ID: 01:00.0 X.Org: 1.7.6 driver: nvidia Resolution: 1280x1024@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: GeForce GTX 550 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.2.0 NVIDIA 304.37 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1: Intel Cougar Point High Definition Audio Controller driver: HDA Intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Card-2: nVidia Device 0bee driver: HDA Intel bus-ID: 01:00.1
Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller 
Drives:    1: ATA ST3500418AS 500.1GB 
           2: USB U3_Cruzer_Micro 2.1GB 
           Optical: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM_GSA-H60N
```

Comment: I would like to know why use the AMD 64bit disc you have intel get the normal 64 bit version and give it a try.

Comment: @markkirby amd64 is the normal 64 bit version of Ubuntu. The amd in there refers to the fact amd was the 1st with a 64 bit.

Comment: So the CD is OK. Did you try booting with acpi=off as a kernel param? (the 1st screen you get should be grub and you can add params to startup after pressing F6)

Comment: I have changed the DVD drive, now I get the first menu without pressing any ESC key, before this first menu I get ERROR "PREFIX" IS NOT SET. When I start with normal DVD drive I get the tipical Ubuntu Menu with language options, when I start with UEFI drive I get another menu without language and only 3 options. I have deleted the option 'quiet' when booting the normal drive, then It seems that the installation hangs after PCI IRQ 16 which is at dmesg | grep -i irq) as PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did install with another ISO: ubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64. However the problem was with my video card and I had to boot in a safe mode and update everything, before I could succeed.

```
Linux ubtxxxx 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.
```